# OpenGL Rendering Speed

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl

I have a question to ask about how to go about sending data through OpenGL. Suppose I have a class called 'Entity'. Entity has a list in it with all the current existing entities. When I want to loop through the list and render each entity, I clear the buffer, push the matrix, fill the VBO with the entity's model data, modify the matrix, then pop the matrix. This seemed to be slow, so I instead of clearing the buffer for every render, I put an entity in once then update its data continually and render the buffer only once. So basically there is 1 buffer, which is rendered every call. This seems to be faster, but since I only render once, I can only modify the matrices once per draw call and can only bind 1 texture at a time. Is this way faster and or better/more efficient than clearing the buffer for every entity and updating it?

I am using OpenGL 4.0

Comment: looks like you are still using fixed pipeline, it dates back to OpenGL 1.0, you aren't using OpenGL 4.0 at all.

Comment: These entities more than likely have a mesh that represents them. Since the mesh may be used by more than one entity you should actually store the vertex data statically per-mesh instead of using a single buffer for every single instance and feeding it new data whenever you draw an instance.

Comment: Matrices are not "filled" with model data. They're used to transform vertices. You suffer from serious misconceptions about OpenGL and should start from scratch learning it. Also OpenGL-4 doesn't have matrices to push and pop.

Comment: @yngum im not using fixed function pipeline I have GLM and use GLSL shaders with VBOS.

Comment: @datenwolf I know matrices are not filled with model data, I just poorly worded my question